# Installing Gitlab 6-1 on Cent OS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, gitlab

I'm following this recipe:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/install/centos/README.md

Step Initialize Database and Activate Advanced Features:
bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production

I can't pass that step, tried several ways of getting to work, create a specific gemset, used the default, and I'm still getting the error as it couldn't find any gem, first it asks for Rake, but it's installed. Tried (without bundle exec) rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production and he asked for another gem, installed the one asked and it asks for another. Tried bundle install, which give me some curious thing, every time I tried it installed all the gems, it didn't show "using gem X (x.x.x)" was "installing gem X (x.x.x)" always.

I'm hoping for someone who passed for such problem installing Gitlab on production and could give me some light how to solve this.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0. RVM. Cent OS 6.2. Gitlabhq 6-1 branch.

Comment: rvm use 2.0.0@gitlab
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 with gemset gitlab
$ which rake
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake

Shouldn't this be /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gitlab/bin/rake instead ?